# How to assign conditional values based on row and formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

I am thinking this is gonna be a simpler answer than I'm making it, but here goes nothing. I have a project I am working on using Excel and Python, where I am going to calculate the results for a season of NASCAR using the different points systems. I had tried doing this only using Python, but figured doing it in Excel first is better. The thing is, I have all the results for all 36 races inputted in Excel, with formatting for drivers who lead a lap, drivers who lead the most laps, and drivers not elligible for points.

**How I have the formatting is as follows:**

> Inelligible driver's names are in red text.
>   Driver(s) who lead a lap are in bold text.
>   Driver(s) who lead the most laps are in bold text and bold border.
>   Driver(s) who had penalties have a red background.

Is there a way I could assign values based on these formatting conditions?
As for the penalties, those I could calculate separately if needed.
Please let me know whatever you may suggest.

Each column contains the results for a single race, and since there are always 43 drivers, the block of cells contains 43 rows (plus a heading row with each race name).

An option I'm thinking of is, to have the results for each race on Sheet1, then on Sheet2 have a list of all valid driver names, then copy and paste it twice, one for each option (2 bonus points, 1 bonus point, and no bonus points), and name each list.  Also, I will have names for each driver, as well as names for each position.  Then, when calculating the points after a race, use an if-then-else formula similar to the following:

IF A2 = driver_most_led [Driver_Name = Driver_Name + Position_Points + Most_Led_Bonus], ELSE IF A2 = driver_lead [Driver_Name = Driver_Name + Position_Points + Lead_Bonus], ELSE [Driver_Name = Driver_Name + Position_Points])

I know it's a long example, but not sure if this is legit or not.

Comment: Can you show how your data is organized? Are the values to determine the conditions are numbers?

Comment: If you are going to change the value of another cell based on formatting you're going to have to use VBA. Worksheet functions can't do that kind of stuff.